# Best Eclipse (Luna) setup with dependent Maven projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse Luna and I have two Maven Java projects A and B where A depends on B.
I want to edit them concurrently (and benefit from Eclipse's refactorization features etc).
What is the best setup for this?

I am currently using the following setup that has some shortcomings, as described below.

I first build project B and install it, and generate an Eclipse project

```
# cd B
B # mvn package install
B # mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I then build A and generate an Eclipse project:

```
# cd ../A
A # mvn package
A # mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I can now import both projects into Eclipse.
My problem is that A now uses the installed B version and not the version that is currently open in Eclipse.
That is, after each update to B, I have to do `mvn install` for B and (apparently) `mvn eclipse:eclipse` for A to see my changes to B reflected in Eclipse.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is, that eclipse:eclipse generate a classpath entry for each dependency like

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar"/>
```

in the file *.classpath* instead of

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
```

I don't know which goal do it better, but when you import your maven projects with the import wizard of eclipse, then the *.classpath* file will be configured with the MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER.

You need the plugin http://eclipse.org/m2e/ to use the dynamic dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Properties* of project `A`, go to *Java Build Path*, and in the *Libraries* tab remove the reference to `M2_REPO/path/to/B-version.jar`. Then, in the *Projects* tab, add a reference to project `B`.

Note that if those are two modules of one parent module (i.e. you have a `pom.xml` with both `A` and `B` in the `<modules>` section) then `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will do this automatically when called on that parent module.